# Problems by installing CVXOPT

Tags: python, cvxopt

I need to install the package cvxopt, but one error occurs:

> c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging1.tmp\cvxopt\src\c\cvxopt.h(31) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'complex.h': No such file or directory
>     error: command C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

+

> You are using pip version 7.0.1, however version 8.1.1 is available.
>   You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Then I write it in cmd and obtain

> Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\user\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages

and it doesn't help because the error is still the same

p.s using win 8.1

Comment: are you using virtual environments?

Comment: That's not an error, that's a warning. You don't have to install the update, although it's highly recommended

Comment: it sound more like you have more python versions... check which one requires update, go to that python version folder, open folder scripts and there is pip executable which you can use for upgrade ... or change python settings in PATH

Comment: @castis yes,you're right

Comment: @Leva7 yes, but nevertheless the problem occurs

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, Download package from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cvxopt%20here)

extract it, navigate inside folder. you will find setup.py file

Now open terminal and type `python setup.py install`

Comment: where should I put the downloaded package?

Comment: after download, extract the content and open the folder. if you want you can move or else let the extracted folder be there only. you will find setup.py file inside the folder. open terminal from that location and type `python setup.py install` it will install package

Comment: it doesn't solve the problem; (can't find 'complex.h' file)

Comment: d:\install\python\cvxopt-1.1.8\src\c\cvxopt.h(31) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'complex.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2